# Bash Scripting with Quotes and Double Quotes

Tags: bash, shell, jmx

I'm trying to run my bash script which is use CJMX client to access SOLR Jmx MBeans.

CJMX has specific rules to run a query.

Example: 
Mbeans names have to be included in single quotes. 
Like: `'solr/collection:type=org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler,id=org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler'`

If MBeans's attribute have more then one word. It has to be included in single quotes. Like: `"Rows Fetched"`

I'm using GETOPTS to parse options. So I have to use quotes to send multiple word options.

Here is my command to run script.

```
./jmx.sh -b solr/collection:type=org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler,id=org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler
-a "Rows Fetched"
```

Then here is my script

```
while getopts ":p:b:a:w:c:s:" OPTION; do
 case "$OPTION" in


      b)
              BEAN="$OPTARG"

              ;;
      a)
              ATTRIBUTE="$OPTARG"
              ;;

  esac
 done

 RESULT=$( $JAVA {Unnecessary} cjmx.Main "mbeans "\'$BEAN\'" select "\"$ATTRIBUTE"\"")
```

Current RESULT command send CJMX wrong phrase. Here:

```
'mbeans '\''solr/song:type=org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler,id=org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler'\'' select "Rows' 'Fetched"'
```

Correct phrase that I have to send CJMX.

```
'mbeans 'solr/song:type=org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler,id=org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler' select "Rows Fetched"'
```

How to fix up quotes to get correct phrase?

Comment: How are you seeing that "current" command? The output from `set -x`? Don't drop out of your double-quotes when you expand the variables in the command and see if that helps. `"mbeans \'$BEAN\' select \"$ATTRIBUTE\""`

Comment: Yes, from set -x.
When i used your advice. I got this,
`'mbeans \'\''solr/song:type=org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler,id=org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler\'\'' select "Rows Fetched"'`

Comment: `set -x` *always* uses single quotes. And, as a result, it *always* "quotes" internal single quotes as `'\''` because that's the only way to do that. It *is not* a reliable way to view a string for this sort of thing. Use `printf %s\\n "$string"` for that (yes, this is counter to most of the advice being *against* using `echo`/`printf` for seeing what is happening.